# Get last value from array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
arr = [[a,1], [b,3], [c,2]]
```

How can I convert the above array into this below:

```
[1,3,2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) & [`last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last):

```
arr.map(&:last)  #=> [1,3,2]
```

this is equivalent to the longer

```
arr.map { |o| o.last }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just simply `arr.map(&:last)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another, more explicit way to perform this operation is with Array#collect:

```
array = [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 2]]
array.collect { |subarray| subarray.last }
```

It just depends on what semantics you need to represent what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If each element is a 2-element array, then just like this

```
arr.map{|x,y| y}
```